# Combining Data Frames (R) and cbind row

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, cbind

Ive got a little question:
I'm combining two data frames like this:
`test <- comp1[comp1$TOKEN %in% comp2$TOKEN,]`
which works well. The problem is that there is another column in comp2 (`comp2$N`) that i want to add to the new data frame test. How do i do this?

Comment: Please provide the sample data frames and output.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for an inner join on `comp1` and `comp2`? Like this:

```
merge(comp1, comp2, by='TOKEN')
```